# Schedule a subroutine to start at a specific time

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to find out if there is an equivalent of Excel's `OnTime` event for PowerPoint 2003; I would like to call a subroutine at a specific time of day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an equivalent to OnTime, but here's another option.  You can create a macro that calls that subroutine, then create a Windows Scheduled Task to call that macro like so:

`"c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\POWERPNT.exe" /M myfile.pptm "MyMacro"`

[Source: Powerpoint command line switches.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint-help/command-line-switches-for-powerpoint-2007-and-the-powerpoint-viewer-2007-HA010153889.aspx)

Comment: Bingo! Very clever, that's a pretty good way of doing it. Wonder why that isn't built in functionality, though.

Comment: Good question.  On the other hand though, this way you don't have to leave Powerpoint open all the time just to run a subroutine once a day.